# Is it good practice to add an event in props.children, to set state in the parent, to set state in a child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to build a control like this...

```
            <ClickLabelEdit labelText='sandwich'>
                <input type='text' value='sandwich' />
                <button onclick={this.closeForm} />
            </ClickLabelEdit>
```

ClickLabelEdit would have two states; show a readonly label and show an editable form for that label.  Click the label and it displays the edit form.  The edit form details would be defined in a property or as children so we could include any type of markup here.  Inside the edit form we will need a hook to tell the control to hide the edit form and display the label again.

This ClickLabelEdit would be a reusable component...used in multiple places around my application.  The data used in the label and the form could be taken from a redux store.  I think the state (or props) that define whether the label or edit form should be displayed doesn't belong in the redux store because that state/prop would have to be duplicated everywhere I use this control which could become messy.

So...

1. where to put the showEditForm prop/state
2. where to put the onclick label function that alters the showEditForm prop/state
3. how to close the edit form and show the label again (this would be triggered from the edit form)

I have got this to work but my main question is it acceptable to use state to trigger events like I have done below, ie

**onclick in children props -> sets state in parent component -> updates state in child**

*ClickLabelEdit.js*

```
class ClickLabelEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { showChildren: this.props.showChildren }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.closeForm === true) {
            this.setState({ showChildren: false });
        }
    }

    onLabelClick() {
        this.setState({ showChildren: true })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.showChildren ?
                        this.props.children
                        :
                        <div onClick={this.onLabelClick.bind(this)}>
                            {this.props.labelValue}
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ClickLabelEdit
```

*usage*

```
class ManualTester extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { value: 'sandwich', closeForm: false }
    }

    onSave() {
        //persist data
        this.setState({ closeForm: true })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ width: 250 }}>
                <ClickTextEdit labelValue={this.state.value} closeForm={this.state.closeForm}>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.value} />
                    <button onClick={this.onSave.bind(this)}>close</button>
                </ClickTextEdit>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ManualTester
```

Comment: I would say this looks like ClickLabelEdit is build as a `controlled custom component` (pattern name by reacttraining). That means you want outer component's influence it's behaviour but also allow it self to handle the behaviour itself using state locally. I have seen it before but this could probably be refactored to not use `componentWillReceiveProps` (maybe) where you use `this.props.closeForm` value instead. I would recommend to skip state in ClickLabelEdit, if not possible, then it's `controlled custom component`

Comment: Yes, I think I need the state inside ClickLabelEdit to enable the clicking of the label and the hiding and showing of the form because those actions are contained within the ClickLabelEdit control.  That's a great heads up on the course (reacttraining) as it is almost exactly what I was trying to achieve and great to have a name to this pattern (controlled custom component).  It feels like I'm kind of doing the right thing (I think my scenario is a little simpler in fact)